# I need a comma separating the 2 outputs without a space between them

Tags: python, formatting

here is my code so far

```
def main():
  dividend = int(input("Please enter an integer for the dividend: "))
  divisor = int(input("Please enter an integer for the divisor: "))
  quotient = dividend//divisor
  remainder = dividend%divisor
  print("The quotient is",quotient, "The remainder is",remainder)


main()
```

the output is---

```
Please enter an integer for the dividend:  6
Please enter an integer for the divisor:  5
The quotient is 1 The remainder is 1
```

However, I need a comma between the two statements so it reads like this

```
Please enter an integer for the dividend:  6
Please enter an integer for the divisor:  5
The quotient is 1, The remainder is 1
```

If I do this---

```
print("The quotient is",quotient,"," "The remainder is",remainder)
```

I get a space between 1 and the comma like this

```
The quotient is 1 , The remainder is 1
```

Comment: Lots of ways to do it.  One way is to use f-strings: `print(f"The quotient is {quotient}, The remainder is {remainder}")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting:

```
print("The quotient is {}, the remainder is {}".format(quotient, remainder)
```

Or if you're on python 3.6+, you can use f-strings:

```
print(f"The quotient is {quotient}, the remainder is {remainder}")
```

Comment: The first one worked when I was using an online compiler, but it did not work in the generic python trinket.  Thanks for reaching out, I appreciate it.

Comment: The string format method was introduced in Python 3.0, so it should work the same in any Python 3 environment.